LaTex: Turning off subsection numbering for a subfile
I'm using a .tex file as a subsection in my main .tex file. In the main.tex file I have:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Section title}

\subfile{sub.tex}

\subsection{Section 3 title}

\end{document}

The sub.tex file is similar to:
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Section 2 title} 

.
.
.

\end{document}

I want to keep the section numbering when I create a PDF of the main.tex file, but I'd like to NOT have the subsection numbering when I generate a standalone PDF from the sub.tex file.
I searched around and found somethings that kind of did what I wanted, but I was hoping, in keeping with the subfiles package, there was an elegant way to do this?

You could change the senumdepth in the preamble of the subfile. This won't influence the main file.
\documentclass[main]{subfiles}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Section 2 title} 

.
.
.

\end{document}


If you'd like to change this for all subfiles:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfiles}

\ifSubfilesClassLoaded{\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}}{}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Section title}

\subfile{sub}

\subsection{Section 3 title}

\end{document}

